# How to remove all but one activity from the stack?

Tags: java, android

I have activities like
A, B, C
Then I want to remove B, C and add D as a one after A (so that when we click BACK in D, we go to A).

How can I do it? Flags do not work, as they clear all, including A.

Comment: Make A the parent activity of the D

Comment: it depends on how you manging navigation like raw using start activity or through jetpack navigation

Comment: > Make A the parent activity of the D – Junaid Khalid

Interesting. How?

MainApplication.getTopActivity().startActivity(intent); does't work, I still go back in stack.

Answer (score 0):

you can also finish the activity when you leave them... eg when you navigate from B -> C, you can finish activity B by calling `finish()` after intent.. and do the same with C -> D.. so when you press back on D.. you will directly go to A

Comment: The problem is, I can not. There are different scenarios of using those activities. So I am looking for a way of doing it either when creating D or when pressing BACK.